# How to add a file to docker using its path?

Tags: docker, sdk, dockerfile

I have a project that need an sdk to be compiled.
This sdk is shared on a server with other users as everyone need it. (It is located under /opt/my-sdk.tar.gz)

My dockerfile lines are :

```
RUN mkdir /sdk
COPY /opt/my-sdk.tar.gz /sdk
RUN cd /sdk && tar xvf my-sdk.tar.gz
```

Then I type in my dockerfile directory :

```
docker build -t myImage .
```

But this error appears :

```
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat opt/my-sdk.tar.gz: file does not exist
```

I think that my docker context doesn't know about /opt but how to solve this as my competences are limited.

Comment: The paths in the `COPY` instructions are relative to the docker context location

Comment: Rather than expect the SDK to be in a particular place when you build the image, it might be more straightforward to download the SDK inside the Dockerfile (`RUN curl ... && tar xzf ...`).

Answer (score 0):

Your docker file should be like this:

```
RUN mkdir /sdk

COPY my-sdk.tar.gz /sdk

WORKDIR /sdk

RUN tar xvf my-sdk.tar.gz
```

But, before you build this, my-sdk.tar.gz has to be in the same path with Dockerfile. You can not copy things from any other locations